# hide custom button based on user profile?

Tags: custom-button

I have one custom detail button in the Account page ,i want to hide that button based on the user profile ?
Is there any way we can do this?

Answer (score 2):

Create a new Page layout and remove that button from it. Assign that page layout to the Profile to which you don't want to show the button.

Comment: Is that any other solution without creating the page layout?

Comment: Not that I know of.

Answer (score 0):

To do what you're asking about you'd need to create a [Dynamic Visualforce Component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_dynamic_vf_components_implementation.htm) based on the `$User.Profile`:

Modified from an example in the documentation:

```
Component.Apex.OutputText renderButton = new Component.Apex.OutputText();
renderButton.expressions.value = 
    '{!IF($User.Profile == "NameofUserRequiredProfile", "True", "False")}';
```

In the above, you'd want to use this type of thing to use to determine whether or not to render the button based on the value of the Profile matching a specific profile where it can be displayed with it not being visible to any other profile. You could modify it accordingly to do the inverse, render the button for everyone except for that specific Profile too, which I believe is closer to what you're asking to do.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible now in lightning. While on the account detail page, click the Setup gear icon and click 'edit' page. Then click the top bar containing the buttons and, at the right Click upgrade to dynamic actions. After upgrading you can set filters for the visibility of the buttons: Press the button on the right side, press 'add filter', press 'Advanced' en then 'Select' Field, go to user to filter on user or to user>Profile to filter on profile.